# Писать "не" или "ни" с глаголом?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

В предложении «Мне кажется, что ни выбери — всё хорошо будет» правильно писать «не» или «ни» с глаголом «выбери»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что ни выбери — всё хорошо будет.

Здесь "ни" усилительная частица (нет отрицания). Предложение "что ни выбери — всё хорошо будет" — сложноподчиненное, "ни" относится к союзному слову "что".

Сочетания *как ни, сколько ни, что ни, когда ни* и др. входят в состав уступительного придаточного.

Например: Когда ни придешь, его нет дома.

Answer (score 1):

**Мне кажется, что ни выбери — всё хорошо будет.**

Речь идет о выборе, а не о его отрицании, здесь НИ - услилительная частица.